# SQL query to set a value if data exist

Tags: mysql

Here's the fiddle;
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af8015/9

I've some data, and I want to set

- if user and g parameter are in table named cl, result column should
  be 1;
- if user and g parameter are in table named im, but not in cl, result
  column should be -1;
- else, result column should be 0

I'm using following query;

```
select *,
    case cl.user_id
       when null then -1
       when im.user_id then 1
    end as result
from im
left join cl     on cl.user_id = im.user_id
                and cl.id_g = im.id_g
left join user   on user.user_id = im.user_id
left join g      on g.id_g = im.id_g
```

But, it returns null for -1, and I couldn't set 0 for the last case.

Expected result table is;

```
user id - g id - result
  1         1     1
  1         2     1
  1         3     0
  1         4     1
  2         1     1
  2         2     1
  2         3    -1
  2         4     0
...
```

Comment: Why does your sequence of `JOIN`s start with the `im` table? One of your requirements seems to involve the possibility that a row will be missing from that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a way of generating the `0` result from your sample data.

I believe your `result` parameter should be computed like this;

```
IF (cl.user_id IS NOT NULL and cl.id_g IS NOT NULL, 1,
    IF(im.user_id IS NOT NULL and im.id_g IS NOT NULL, -1,0)
   ) result
```

And, I think your series of JOIN operations should go like this.

```
FROM user
LEFT JOIN im ON user.user_id = im.user_id
LEFT JOIN cl ON user.user_id = cl.user_id AND im.id_g = cl.id_g 
LEFT JOIN g  ON im.id_g = g.id_g
```

That is, you should lead with the `user` table. Here's an example:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5c6ef/1/0

Your `result` parameter is computed like this:

```
 case cl.user_id
    when null then -1
    when im.user_id then 1
 end as result
```

`null` values work strangely. A `null` value can never compare equal to anything, even another `null` value, so `when null then -1` will never fire.  This expression, on the other hand, should work.

```
 case when cl.user_id IS NULL then -1
      when im.user_id IS NULL then 1
      else 0 end as result
```